# Which OpenCV FOURCC codecs should I use for my Python program?

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I have implemented a Python script which displays a video to the user and records it. The video is saved either compressed or uncompressed.

In an old program I have seen, that the "DIVX" MPEG-4 and the "IYUV" codecs were used. For some reason, they don't work on my computer (OUTPUT_VIDEO is a MP4-file).

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x58564944/'DIVX' is not supported with codec id 13 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x00000020/' ???'
```

The "MPJPG" codec works with ".avi" files.

Because I'm not sure about the codecs, I would like to ask, which codecs should I use for my script to achieve the following requirements:

- the video sequence can be saved as **.mp3**, **.mp4** file (both compressed) or as **.avi** file (uncompressed).
- Python script should work on Windows and Linux platforms.

This is my source code:
**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import cv2
import platform

#=========== TO CHANGE ===========
INPUT_VIDEO = os.path.join("..", "resources", "video.mp4")
OUTPUT_VIDEO = os.path.join("..", "recorded", "recorded.avi")
compress = False
#=========== TO CHANGE ===========

WINDOW_NAME = "Video Recorder"

player = cv2.VideoCapture(INPUT_VIDEO)

# Get the frames per second (fps) of the video.
fps = player.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

# Get width and height via the video capture property.
width = player.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
height = player.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object according to the used operating system.
four_cc = None
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    if compress:
        four_cc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")  # *"DIVX")  # DIVX MPEG-4 codec.
    else:
        four_cc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")  # *"IYUV")  # Uncompressed yuv420p in avi container.
elif platform.system() == "Linux":
    if compress:
        four_cc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"DIVX")  # DIVX MPEG-4 codec.
    else:
        four_cc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"IYUV")  # Uncompressed yuv420p in avi container.

recorder = cv2.VideoWriter(OUTPUT_VIDEO, four_cc, fps, (int(width), int(height)))

if player is None:
    quit()

while player.isOpened():
    ret, frame = player.read()

    if ret:
        cv2.imshow(WINDOW_NAME, frame)
        recorder.write(frame)
    else:
        break

    key_code = cv2.waitKey(1)

    # Closes the window if the ESC key was pressed.
    if key_code == 27:
        break

    # Closes the window if the X button of the window was clicked.
    if cv2.getWindowProperty(WINDOW_NAME, 1) == -1:
        break

player.release()
recorder.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm using a Windows 7 computer, with opencv-contrib-python 3.4.0.12 and Python 3.6.

Comment: I am using OpenCV 4.2.0.32 and Windows 10. For `mp4` format, `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")` is working (MPEG-4 codec), and for uncompressed `avi`, `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"RGBA")` is working. `mp3` is an audio container, it's irrelevant. In terms of quality, H.264 codec is better than MPEG-4, but H.264 codec encoding support requires an extra DLL (in Windows).  For AVI, using `RGBA` is a waist of space, because there are 4 bytes per pixel, instead of 3. I couldn't find the fourcc  for BGR (it used to be `' DIB' `).

Comment: It works! https://imgur.com/cGDgmY5 It can produce both DIVX and IYUV video on Windows 7 with Python 3.6 and opencv-python 3.4.0.12.

Comment: @DanielKoch Many thanks for your reply! Now it works for me too. I've found out that the video files (.mp4 and .avi) were produced correctly even though the error message is displayed in PyCharm IDE Community Edition 2017.2.3. I've found these two codecs in an old C++ program, which was implemented for Linux platforms.